# String member variable of an object used in C++ Class template cannot be assigned to

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I wrote a class template for an array data structure like so:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T, unsigned int N>
class CArray {
public:
    CArray();
    T& operator [] (unsigned int index);
private:
    T *entries;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int N>
CArray<T, N>::CArray()
{
    entries = (T *)malloc(N*sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T, unsigned int N>
T& CArray<T, N>::operator [] (unsigned int index) {
    if (index >= N) {
        throw ;
    } else {
        return entries[index];
    }
}
```

I wrote a minimal wrapper class that stores string objects, like so:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CEntry
{
public:
    CEntry();
    const string & getSymbol() const;
    void setSymbol(string);
protected:
    string m_value;
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "CEntry.hpp"

CEntry::CEntry() : m_value(""){
}

const string & CEntry::getSymbol() const {
    return  m_value;
}

void CEntry::setSymbol(string value) {
    m_value = value;
}
```

When i execute the following main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "CEntry.hpp"
#include "CArray.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CArray<CEntry, 2000> test;
    test[0].setSymbol("asdf");
    cout << test[0].getSymbol();
}
```

The program crashes with a segmentation fault.
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffad1783f2a in msvcrt!memmove () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll

I inspected the program and the crash happens directly in the line of CEntry, where m_value gets assigned to the passed value (in the setSymbol function).
I am using eclipse on windows. I inspected the m_value variable before assignment and it shows suspect values, e.g. 13451671603782742029 for the string length? Could it be that the CEntry object was initialized but not it's member variables?

I've tried researching but cannot figure out whats happening here, thanks in advance.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I debugged the program - please read the text i wrote below! Also, this is the minimal example i can reproduce it with, the original code is much longer.

Comment: Avoid `malloc`. Why not use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You seem to overestimate the ability of the debugger to tell an inexperienced programmer what they're doing wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: OP uses correctly its debugger, but internal of `std::string` is not necessary trivial. OP uses its allocator wrongly in fact.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is crashing because you are accessing unconstructed `string` objects.

When you use `malloc` to allocate memory, the memory is uninitialized and the objects you are trying to use have not been constructed.  This is Undefined Behavior and, in this case, is causing the crash.

Comment: Thanks, that caused the issue.

Comment: Replacing the malloc with  new T[N]; fixed it